# jQuery animated sticky header on scroll - swap image problem

Tags: jquery

I got some 'animated sticky header' code from a jQuery tutorial online. It's working fine except that I want to change the logo image as the header animation occurs. I've tried editing the code but can't get it to work (my bad!)

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="menu" id="fixed">

<div id="logo"><img id="logo-img" src="svg/logo-200-red-border.svg" width="120" height="120"></div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


</div> <!-- .menu -->
```

The jQuery I'm using is as follows:

```
;(function($){
'use strict';

 var defaults = {
    topOffset: 400, //px - offset to switch of fixed position
    hideDuration: 300, //ms
    stickyClass: 'is-fixed'
};

$.fn.stickyPanel = function(options){
    if(this.length == 0) return this; // returns the current jQuery object

    var self = this,
        settings,
        isFixed = false, //state of panel
        stickyClass,
        animation = {
            normal: self.css('animationDuration'), //show duration
            reverse: '', //hide duration
            getStyle: function (type) {
                return {
                    animationDirection: type,
                    animationDuration: this[type]
                };
            }
        };

    // Init carousel
    function init(){
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        animation.reverse = settings.hideDuration + 'ms';
        stickyClass = settings.stickyClass;
        $(window).on('scroll', onScroll).trigger('scroll');

    }

    // On scroll
    function onScroll() {
        if ( window.pageYOffset > settings.topOffset){
            if (!isFixed){
                isFixed = true;
                self.addClass(stickyClass)
                    .css(animation.getStyle('normal'));
                self.attr( "src", "svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg" );

            }
        } else {
            if (isFixed){
                isFixed = false;

                self.removeClass(stickyClass)
                    .each(function (index, e) {
                        // restart animation
                        // https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
                        void e.offsetWidth;
                    })
                    .addClass(stickyClass)
                    .css(animation.getStyle('reverse'));


                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.removeClass(stickyClass);
                }, settings.hideDuration);
            }
        }
    }


    init();
    return this;


}
})(jQuery);


//run
$(function () {
    $('#fixed').stickyPanel();
});
```

So, my question is - how do I edit the jQuery code obove to change the current 'logo' image ( to another image AS THE HEADER ANIMATES?

In my ignorance, I tried the adding:

```
self.attr( "src", "svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg" );
```

to the jQuery:

```
// On scroll
    function onScroll() {
        if ( window.pageYOffset > settings.topOffset){
            if (!isFixed){
                isFixed = true;
                self.addClass(stickyClass)
                    .css(animation.getStyle('normal'));
                self.attr( "src", "svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg" );

            }
        } else {
```

... but (surprise) without success!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure `svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg` exists ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes, it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need an image tag at all?  Can you just have 2 css classes each with a different background image and just toggle classes in your jquery code?

#### css

```
.normal-logo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-image: url('svg/logo-200-red-border.svg');
}


.sticky-logo {
  background-image: url('svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg');
}
```

#### jquery

just remove this:

```
self.attr( "src", "svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg" );
```

#### html

```
<div id="logo" class="normal-logo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Tried changing both lines of code to 'this' - but this causes the animation to fail completely. Changing the second line only to: this.attr( "src", "svg/logo-rs-layer-200-w.svg" ); doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks! That works! I got stuck on trying to edit jQuery code - didn't think about using CSS.

Comment: Have accepted your answer. Once again, many thanks for your help.